# why is mpeg4 encoder faster than libx264 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, x264, mpeg4

I have been padding mp4 videos so they can become of the size `1920x1080` instead of `1920x800`. I used initially used `mpeg4` encoder using ffmpeg, the encoding was quick but the size of the file was more than 5 times larger than the original.

I decided to use `libx264` encoder instead but the encoding process was much slower than the mpeg4 encoder although the size of the output was close to the original file.

I use `-q:v 0` for the best quality, and I am intending to encode using the best possible quality. Is there an encoder that would encode `x264` as fast as `mpeg4` encoder, or at least faster than `libx264` encoder?

Comment: H.264 is a more complex codec and you sacrifice time/processing power encoding and decoding the stream to save on size.  H.264 is almost always going to take longer.

Comment: Why pad? Any decent player should handle the aspect ratio properly.

Comment: I need to add subtitles in an AVCHD folder so I would be able to play foreign movies on PS3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that if you don't mind a larger file size, you can use `-preset ultrafast` and the speed will be similar to `mpeg4` encoder for `libx264` encoder