# is there anything faster than "-preset ultrafast" in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using `-preset ultrafast` to adding watermark as fast as possible in the video.

I want to know just for knowledge or curiosity is anything faster than `-preset ultrafast` in FFmpeg to add watermark in the video very fast.

Comment: Depending the encoder you're using in FFMPEG https://superuser.com/questions/943556/why-is-mpeg4-encoder-faster-than-libx264-using-ffmpeg?rq=1

Comment: No, ultrafast is fastest for x264.

Comment: and what for mpeg?

Comment: Hardware encoders are probably a little faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the x264 encoder, there is no faster preset. See `x264 --fullhelp` for a list of possible presets.

The presets are also the same for x265.

Note that with `ultrafast`, you will be getting much larger files with lower quality than what you'd get if you could wait a little longer for the encode.

Hardware encoders such as NVENC (or others, [see Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro)) can be much faster than x264. If live-streaming is what you're after, you should have a look at this.